# What does the term "sneaker zoom" mean?

Tags: lens, terminology

I saw the term used when describing the Canon 85mm f/1.8. What do they mean?

Comment: @Francesco I initially imagined some sort of ninja zoom that just comes out of nowhere :p

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It means the lens focal length doesn't change, but you can change the framing by moving your feet — which in this idiom are wearing sneakers (which, for non-native English speakers, are [casual athletic shoes](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneaker_(footwear))). I've more commonly heard "zoom with your feet", which is the same thing except not dependent on shoe style.

It important to be aware that changing your position is *not* the same as zooming, because moving alters perspective, while zooming does not. To get the effect of zoom with a fixed-focal-length lens, don't move — *crop*.

Comment: Bonus +1 for the advice about perspective.

Answer (score 7):

you walk closer or farther from your subject.